# Classification of K-nearest neighbours algorithm

Tags: algorithm, knn

The x and y axis have different scales in this scatter plot.
Assume the centre of each shape to be the datapoint.

[image: scatter diagram of for pet, wild and unknown dogs]

Q: What will be the classification of a test point for 9-nearest- neighbour classifier using this training set, use both features?

Q: On the scatter plot at the top of the page, in any order, name the class of three nearest neighbours for the bottom left unknown point, using both features to compute distance.

---

Here's my attempt:

1: A higher K, 9 in this case, that more voters in each prediction and hence is more resilient to outliers. Larger values of K will have smoother decision boundaries to decide either Pet or Wild here, which means lower variance but increased bias.

2: By using the Pythagorean theorem, the distance of the three nearest classes to the bottom left unknown point are,

1. Pet, Distance = 0.02
2. Pet, Distance = 2.20
3. Wild, Distance = 2.60

Therefore, the class is Pet.

Comment: Have you attempted your homework? We're here to help, but only after you make a reasonable attempt yourself.

Comment: Hi, I just attempted and posted below. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Am I missing something or are using 9-nearest neighbors classifier when all but 4 animals are wild? (I assume the "unknown" points are as usual intended to be classified, and you don't perform any weighting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 asks for a specific answer (Pet or Wild), which you have not provided. The statements you've made are generally true, but they don't actually answer the question. Notice that there are only 4 Pet points, and the rest are Wild. So no matter which 9 points are the nearest neighbors, at least 5 (a majority) will be Wild. Hence, a KNN classifier with K = 9 will always predict Wild using this data.

Question 2 looks mostly right. I don't have the exact coordinates of the points, but your numbers seem to be in the right ballpark, except you probably have a typo in the first distance. The classes are right, and the resulting prediction (which the question didn't explicitly ask for) is also right (assuming K = 3).

Comment: yup, the first one should be 0.2 instead.